# What is the difference between proprietary codecs and open source ones?

Tags: video, license, codec, open-source

Let's say H.264 is a proprietary codec which is protected by patents [owned by various parties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC).  However, there is a open source h264 encoder called "x264".  Do I need to pay royalty fee for using open source codecs?

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the particular codecs. If the codec is freely distributed, the difference between proprietary and open-source would not be of concern to you as end-user *unless you plan to distribute the codec yourself*.

If you *do* want to distribute the software, then read the license information to see if it allows distribution (e.g. [GNU "copyleft"](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/copyleft.en.html)) or contact the codec vendor. The GNU license is free to use and distribute, and you cannot charge for its use. Other licenses vary; contact the vendor.

**N.B.** If a third party were to make available a codec that violates copyright of the original owner, you might be breaking the law in distributing it.

Comment: Thnaks for the reply, what about the royalty fee? Do I have to pay to use a open source encoder (x264) which the standard (H.264) is patent protected?